Why did the LORD choose the conduit of the upper pool as the place for Isaiah to meet Ahaz? Isaiah 7:3
Isaiah 7:3  ESV

"And the LORD said to Isaiah, "Go out to meet Ahaz, you and Shear-jashub your son, at the end of the conduit of the upper pool on the highway to the Washer's field."

In 1 John 4:14 is, "the Father has sent his Son to be the Saviour of the world." Did the upper pool send water to the lower pool? ["Lower pool", Isaiah 22:9].
Is their any symbolic meaning attached to the upper pool making it a particularly significant place for Isaiah and his son to meet with Ahaz?

Yes to the question about the upper pool sending water to the lower pool. That is implied by the fact that there was a conduit between the two.
When we get to symbolic meanings, that is a matter of opinion. It could simply a meeting place, like telling someone today to go to the corner of Reservoir Road and Fuller Street (the text describes the lower pool as a "fuller's field.") Among the rabbinical commentators there are some opinions that the upper pool was a fish pond and the lower one was where people washed clothes. The upper pool was clean but the lower one was polluted. Ahaz, who was fearful of any sign from God (vs. 12), supposedly fled there in shame. This could relate to the question of why God told Isaiah to meet Ahaz where he did, if one believes that God knew that Ahaz would react shamefully and provided an appropriate place for him to hide among the launderers, or even under the laundry.
In connection with  1 John 4:14, Jesus is said to give "living water" (from the upper pool?) while the lower pool represents polluted water. But personally I see it as a stretch to interpret this as the reason for the meeting place.

Isaiah 22:11 "you did not look to the one who did it", i.e. provided water. When the "breaches of the city of David were many". Is 22:9. Jerusalem under attack but God makes a system [the one who did it] for those inside. God has provided water/protection; meet  at a place where this His providence is illustrated. [?]

+1. Good answer - this is about as much as one can say without excessive speculation.

@C.Stroud  - Water is a pretty fluid symbol :-) In Revelation it is peoples, multitudes, nations and tongues. In John's gospel it is eternal life.  For Paul they become the womb in which we are reborn. In the Psalms the waters of Babylon symbolize the sadness of separation from Jerusalem. The waters of the Jordan symbolize the dividing line between God's realm and the evil sovereignty; and in song they become like the river Styx in Greek mythology.  And this is not even close to being a complete list.
